# Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference for setAdapter

Tags: android

I am getting the following error when I open my app as a result of which the apl crashes right on start

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)' on a null object reference
        at com.akash.writer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43)
```

Comment: Please attach the code of MainActivty,java also

Comment: Also see [how to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You should include your code to get a useful answer.

Comment: Seems like you're trying to setting the adapter to recycler view without initializing it.

Please initialize your recycler view before setting adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error message it's seems like you're trying to set adapter to recycelrView without initializing it. Please initialize the recyclerView before setting adapter to it.

As you're using JAVA here is a rough example how you could initialize your recyclerView

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.id.your_layout)

    //Initialize your recycler view first
    RecyclerView yourRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.your_recycler_view_id)

    //now set your adapter to your recycler view
    yourRecyclerView.setAdapter(yourAdapter)
}
```